# Nested unique ng-model per ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently creating a page that has nested ng-repeats and ng-models. The ng-models are based off an $index.

http://codepen.io/natdm/pen/vOzaPj?editors=101 (since jsfiddle had an out-dated Angular)

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('teamController', function($scope) {

    $scope.league = { teams: 5,
                     format: 4}

    $scope.toArray = function(team) {
        return new Array(team);
    };

    $scope.log = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    };

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="teamController">
    <h1>Create Teams</h1>

    <table ng-repeat="t in toArray(league.teams) track by $index">
        <thead class="col-md-6">
        <tr>
            <th>Team {{$index + 1}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="col-md-6">
        <tr>
            <td>Team Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="team.team_name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in toArray(league.format) track by $index">
            <td>Player {{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="team.player_+[$index + 1]"/></td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button ng-click="log(team)">Test</button>

</div>
```

I'm pulling the number of teams and players per team from a Factory. They equate to just two numbers. Maybe 5 teams with 4 players each. This would make a page with five repeating tables, having rows for 4 players and a team name, each.

I'm trying to think of a way to send these to the database. Since this page is rendered off the amount of teams and players, the only way to make the ng-models are off of an $index.

The database has the following columns (subject to change if needed):

- team_id (unique, created upon insert)
- league_id (unique per team, this gets carried over from a factory)
- team_name
- player_1
- player_2
- player_3 (accepts null)
- player_4 (accepts null)
- player_5 (accepts null)
- player_6 (accepts null)
- standing
- paid
- createdAt
- updatedAt

How can I have one page with repeating team fields upload multiple teams at once with one $http.put request?

Further more, maybe a smaller issue, with the way I have it set, it's forcing the input of each text to be the ng-model name. That'd have to change.

Comment: I think you are looking at this backwards.  If you design the model you want in the controller, the `ng-repeat` will fall into place.  The approach you are taking is much more the JQuery way of thinking, trying to build the model based on the DOM.  This won't work, as the multiple messages about infinite digests will probably attest.  I'm looking at the code now, to see if I can suggest the angular way to do this.

Comment: @Vanojx1 just posted a structure similar to what I was already starting to toy around with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to parse your structure in a new one

```
$scope.parseLeague = [];

for(var i=0;i<$scope.league.teams ;i++){
  $scope.parseLeague.push({team: "team_"+i, players: []});
  for(var j=0;j<$scope.league.format;j++){
    $scope.parseLeague[i].players.push("player_"+j);
  }
}
```

then inside the html you need to change the repeat with the new structure

```
<table ng-repeat="team in parseLeague track by $index">
```

with

```
<tr>
    <td>Team Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="team.name"/></td>
</tr>
```

and

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in team.players track by $index">
    <td>Player {{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="player"/></td>
</tr>
```

the http request

```
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "yoururl",
    data: { teamsdata: angular.toJson($scope.parseLeague)}
});
request.success(
    function( risp ) {
        //handle your risp
    }
);
```

working pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGaaRP?editors=101

Comment: What would the http.post request look like?

Comment: i will add the request

Comment: is your backend php based??

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and answer today.

Comment: No sir. NodeJS/Postgres.

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work. Still a little 'magical' but I'll understand it after a few reads.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('teamController', function($scope) {
    $scope.team={};
    $scope.league = { teams: 5,
                     format: 4}

    $scope.toArray = function(team) {
        return new Array(team);
    };

    $scope.log = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="teamController">
    <h1>Create Teams</h1>

    <table  ng-repeat="p in toArray(league.teams) track by $index">
        <thead class="col-md-6">
        <tr>
            <th>Team {{$index + 1}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="col-md-6">
        <tr>
            <td>Team Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="team['team_'+($index+1)].team_name"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in toArray(league.format) track by $index" ng-init="innerIndex=$index">
            <td>Player  {{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="team['team_'+($parent.$index+1)].player['player_'+(innerIndex + 1)]"/></td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button ng-click="log(team)">Test</button>
  <div>
  JSON: <br>{{team}}
  </div>

</div>
```